# Service bus trigger on azure function starts new azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function deployed that listens on service bus messages.

Whilst I was testing I realised that the the same azure function instance picked up the service bus message as data wrote to a file I was not expecting.

What I thought would happen is that a new instance of an azure function would launch when each new message is added to the service bus. Am I wrong in this understanding? or can this be achieved and I need to set some type of flag so once my function dequeues a message it stops listening, so any future service bus entries get picked up on a new azure function instance

Thanks

EDIT:

This is the function declaration

```
 [FunctionName("ServiceBusShopifyTrigger")]
    public async Task ServiceBusTrigger([ServiceBusTrigger("%serviceBusShopifyExtractQueue%", Connection = "serviceBusExtractConnectionString")] string msg, int deliveryCount, DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc, string messageId)
    {
```

I have placed the following in the start of the function:

```
string instanceid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID");
        _logger.LogInformation($"****** Orch Shopify - Azure Function Instance ID: {instanceid}");
```

As I understand this should be unique for each azure instance that spins up. However, I am seeing this as the same each time the function exectues

I also have a HTTP Trigger function and again the Instance ID is the same

Looking at the monitoring I am seeing the following for HTTP Trigger (note the operation ID on closely triggered functions)

[image: OperationId duplciates]
These 2 instances were triggered from 2 seperate Http calls

For the service bus monitoring I am seeing different operation ids for closely triggered functions.

[image]

Something that I have just noticed in the following:

[image]

- The calls at 13:26 share the same WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID
- The call at 13:40 share the same WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID as the calls at 13:26
- The call at 15:14 has a different WEBSITE_INSTACE_ID

Comment: can you share some code? Your assumption is correct, each message will start a new instance of a function

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio please see the edits above for some more info